# PHP bind parameters $mysqli->prepare() statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hi I am not too sure what is wrong with what I have written. A friend has simular code but mine wont work. Would appreciate help.

```
if (isset($_GET['postID']))
{
    $postID = $_GET['postID'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT postTitle FROM Posts WHERE postID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $postID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($postTitle);
    echo $postTitle;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Oh! Terribly sorry! My mistake.. Misread the post, had pdo in mind :( Deleting comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not fetched results with [`$stmt->fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). Although you have bound your result column to `$postTitle`, no value will be available unless you fetch a row from the statement result set.

```
// First, don't forget to establish your connection
$mysqli = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

if (isset($_GET['postID']))
{
    $postID = $_GET['postID'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT postTitle FROM Posts WHERE postID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $postID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($postTitle);

    // Use a while loop if multiple rows are expected,
    // Otherwise, a single call to $stmt->fetch() will do.
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $postTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly that still didnt work the error says Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Users/user/Sites/php/post.php on line 29

Comment: line 29 is $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT postTitle FROM Posts WHERE postID = ?");

Comment: That would mean your connection $mysqli was not successfully created.  You did call new mysqli(),  right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. I didn't make a new instance of $mysqli I now have a problem as it is not getting the content. It retrieves every other field, just not the content.

Comment: @user1136076 You'll need to post your code, possibly as a new question. I can't deduce what you mean from your comment.